# icc compiler and strtok

Tags: strtok, icc

When I try to compile my code with `icc` I get an error (compiling on a HPC cluser):

```
properties.cpp(51): error: identifier "strtok" is undefined
```

I think this is an issue of missing header, however, when I compile with `gcc` on my local machine there is no error. How can I compile it then? Is it an issue with some sort of library that has been moved? I tried searching for some information about `strock` and `icc` and didn't find any thing usefull.

Alternatively, is there a replacement command for `strtok`? I use it to read data from file (`=` is my tocken).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like icc-avr requires `#include <string.h>` for strtok() - which makes sense as it will follow most other implementations then

See http://www.manpagez.com/man/3/strtok/